# java null pointer exception but has already initialized

Tags: java, android

stacktrack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean' java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference  
at android.net.LinkProperties.<init>(LinkProperties.java:159)
at com.android.server.ConnectivityService.getUnfilteredActiveNetworkState(ConnectivityService.java:957)
at com.android.server.ConnectivityService.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityService.java:1024)
at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:696)
at
```

linkproperties.java:

```
public final class LinkProperties implements Parcelable {
// The interface described by the network link.
private String mIfaceName;
private ArrayList<LinkAddress> mLinkAddresses = new ArrayList<LinkAddress>();
private ArrayList<InetAddress> mDnses = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();
private String mDomains;
private ArrayList<RouteInfo> mRoutes = new ArrayList<RouteInfo>();
...
public LinkProperties(LinkProperties source) {
    if (source != null) {
        mIfaceName = source.getInterfaceName();
        for (LinkAddress l : source.getLinkAddresses()) mLinkAddresses.add(l);
        for (InetAddress i : source.getDnsServers()) mDnses.add(i);
        mDomains = source.getDomains();
        for (RouteInfo r : source.getRoutes()) mRoutes.add(r);
        mHttpProxy = (source.getHttpProxy() == null)  ?
                null : new ProxyInfo(source.getHttpProxy());
        for (LinkProperties l: source.mStackedLinks.values()) {
            addStackedLink(l);
        }
        setMtu(source.getMtu());
        mTcpBufferSizes = source.mTcpBufferSizes;
    }
}
```

In the stacktrace we can find this exception in happened in init method , that means when construct this data, while doing ArrayList.add method , throw a NullPointerException . So in the constructor method ,only **mLinkAddresses** , **mDnses** and **MRoutes** these three ArrayLists , but they all have been initialized. So I was confusing about this.

All Arraylist has been init before create ,but still get `NullPointerException`, and this issue only happened on MTK platform.

Comment: which is line 159?

Comment: Yes, which is line 159. Also, are you sure you've cleaned and rebuilt your project, so this is the code that's actually running? Finally, have you tried moving the initialization of the `ArrayList` fields into the constructor itself?

Comment: @Ted Hopp I can certain sure ArrayLists in constructor method that's only these three fields . and all of them has been initialized. this code is the AOSP, and you guys can have a look at this http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/LinkProperties.java

Comment: How about the line `addStackedLink(l);` ? Where is this method?

Comment: This stacktrace does not come from the linked code.. There's no ArrayList#add at line 159

Comment: @RC `mLinkAddresses.add(l)` `mDnses.add(i)` and `mRoutes.add(r)` looks like `boolean ArrayList#add(Object)` ;) EDIT : ow, linked code ...

Comment: @ihsan.gaozp it is time to use debugger ... check fi the List are null or not at runtime.

Comment: Looking through all versions of `LinkProperties.java`, it seems that none of them has a call to `add()` on line 159. Could it be that MTK mucked about with the library when they build their phone's OS?

Answer (score 0):

Method parameter `LinkProperties source` is not null but when call `source.getLinkAddresses(),source.getDnsServers(),source.getRoutes()` may have null value.You have to check this.

Comment: If that were the problem, the error message and stack trace would be completely different.